# Internal devices cannot access VirtualBox guest centos

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, apache-http-server

My host ( Ubuntu ) can access to the webpage-wordpress running on VirtualBox guest centos8. But the other devices on the internal network cannot. The network setting is Bridged. I added some rules to host in ufw and port forward to the guest but nothing happened. In addition I have disabled the firewalld.service in centos for a while. The ufw rules:

```
To                   Action   From
--                   ------   ----
192.168.1.72 80      ALLOW    Anywhere
192.168.1.72 443     ALLOW    Anywhere
192.168.1.72 80/tcp  ALLOW    Anywhere
192.168.1.72 443/tcp ALLOW    Anywhere
```

As you can guess the guest's IP is .1.72

I have done this before with KVM and all devices can access the server. Is it possible with VirtualBox?

Comment: It is definitely possible with VirtualBox, I use a similar config and my guest VM is accessible from other devices on the network. Sorry I can't advise on your particular situation.

Comment: Thank you. Eventually there were some rules in IPtables that didn't allow the access. Everything is fine now